# Trouble setting selected value of strongly typed MVC SelectList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

Get the data from the database and tack on the option I plan to be the default selected:

```
    public List<Forester> GetForesters()
    {
        var data = _db.tblForester.ToList();

        List<Forester> ForesterList = new List<Forester>();

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Person person = new Person()
            {
                Key_ = item.Key_,
                FirstName = item.FirstName,
                LastName = item.LastName,
                District = item.District,
                County = item.County
            };
            PersonList.Add(person);
        }
        PersonList.Add(new Person { Key_ = -1, FirstName = "- Select ", LastName = "Person -" } );
        return PersonList;
    }
```

Model has two properties:

```
    public int SelectedPersonId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PersonList { get; set; }
```

Controller gets the list from the database and makes a selectlist:

```
        vm.SelectedPersonId = -1;
        vm.PersonList = new SelectList(repo.GetPeople(), "Key_", "PersonsName", vm.SelectedpersonId);
```

I have tried a couple ways in the view:

```
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Key_, new SelectList( Model.PersonList, "Value", "Text", -1), new { @class = "form-control ddl" })
```

The dropdown works great, except the selected value is the just the first on the list, not the one I specify.

Here is how the HTML renders:

```
<form action="/Forester/Activity" method="post"><select class="form-control ddl" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Key_ must be a number." data-val-required="The Key_ field is required." id="Key_" name="Key_"><option value="1">DIANE PARTRIDGE</option>
<option value="2">GARY GROTH</option>
```

...

The one I added is at the bottom:

```
<option value="-1">- Select   Forester -</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the following model

```
 public int SelectedPersonId { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PersonList { get; set; }
```

you should use

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPersonId , Model.PersonList, new { @class = "form-control ddl" })
```

`DropDownListFor` helper will evaluate SelectedPersonId and it will try to select it

Comment: Also, the line where you set `vm.PersonList` should not construct a `SelectList`. Just do `repo.GetPeople().Select(m => new SelectListItem { ... })` to construct your `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: Thanks guys, working now.  As to the controller line, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following, the last parameter specifies the initial text (option label) so you will not need to use a dummy -1 value:

```
 Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPersonId, 
          Model.PersonList as List<SelectListItem>, "Select   Forester -"})
```

[**SelectExtensions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)